# Trabalhando com o resultado do retorno de uma requisição ajax com jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, return, requisição

Gostaria de saber se é possível comparar um valor retornado de uma função Ajax com uma variável externa utilizando o jquery.

Quando tento fazer a comparação percebo que a variável externa não é reconhecida dentro da função do Ajax.

Como posso fazer esta verificação conforme segue o exemplo?

```
    $(document).ready(funcntion(e){
    var variavel = 123; //define um valor
    //busca um valor para a comparação
    $.ajax({
        url:'script.php',
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(result){
            //verifica se retornou um objeto
            if(typeof(result) == 'object') {
                //separa o valor retornado
                var num = result[0];
                //comparar o valor retornado com a variável declarada           
                    if(num == variavel){
                        alert('o valor é igual');
                    }else{
                        alert('o valor é diferente');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Function` na primeira linha está escrito errado. Esqueceu do ultimo parenteses e ponto e virgula para fechar o `.ready()`.

Além disso, é provável que o seu `num` não esteja recebendo o `result`, pois notei que está tentando receber um objeto porém está passando o valor como se fosse um array. A melhor forma de verificar isso é colocando um `console.log(result)` logo após o `if` para ver como o resultado chega na aplicação

```
   $(document).ready(function(e){
    var variavel = 123; //define um valor
    //busca um valor para a comparação
    $.ajax({
        url:'script.php',
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(result){
            //verifica se retornou um objeto
            if(typeof(result) == 'object') {
                console.log(result);
                var num = result[0]; // veja o formato com que o result chega se for objeto passe como var num = result.campo;
                //comparar o valor retornado com a variável declarada           
                    if(num == variavel){
                        alert('o valor é igual');
                    }else{
                        alert('o valor é diferente');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Agradeço pelas observações foram erros de digitação e o código não foi colocado em teste para verificar estas condições. Resolvi o problema transformado a variável em tipo global. De qualquer maneira agradeço pela sua atenção